# how to filter from nested collections without ForEach?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, nested, iteration

I have an entity say Type A with property type List of B. Type B also has a property of type List of C.

I want to apply the filter on object of A such that there would be only C objects in the List of C for which their Selected property is True.

This can be done like:

```
A objA = A.ListB.ForEach(b => {b.ListC.RemoveAll(c => c.Selected == false);});
```

But I don't have to remove all those C Objects which have Selected = false. I only want to filter them.

Any ideas?

---

**More explanation:** There is an object of Type A, with List of B property. In each B object of A's List of B, there exists a List of C property. 
C object has a Selected Property. Now, all I need is- an object of A with List of B, where in each of B's List of C has only those C objects which have Selected = true.
The desirable output is type A. List B shouldn't be filtered only List C needs to be filtered.

Comment: define "filter" vs "remove" here? what is your desired result?

Comment: by "filter" I meant to SELECT only desirable records in some other object of Type A. On "removing" it removes the undesired objects of ListC from the source object of type A.
I dont want the source to be changed, I only need a filtered copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
A.ListB.Where( b => b.ListC.Exists( c => c.Selected ) )
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks mrz, I dont want to filter ListB. I want to only filter ListC

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list containing all the selected C objects, you can do this:

```
List<C> selectedC = A.ListB.SelectMany( b => b.ListC.Where( c => c.Selected)).ToList();
```

Comment: I need the object of Class A- with each of B object in its ListB property having a list of C where C.Selected == true.

Answer (score 0):

```
var qry = from b in A.ListB
          select new {B=b,ListC=b.ListC.Where(x => x.Selected).ToList()};
```

note that this is just an anonymous tuple; we can't show code to reconstruct an `A`/`B` etc without more info on how your code is structured, what props there are, etc